# Spread match on consequent following lines

Tags: regex

Please consider this sample:

```
header-1
    item1-1
    item1-2
    item1-3
header-2
    item2-1
    item2-2
...
```

and I want it in this format:

```
header-1 item1-1
header-1 item1-2
header-1 item1-3
header-2 item2-1
header-2 item2-2
...
```

I guess there is easy way to do this with regex, but I just can't figure out

Any regex syntax is welcomed, I use RegexBuddy under Wine

Comment: Don't try to use a regex for this, it will just end up being complex and unreadable. Which programming language are you using?

Comment: `to do this with regex` - now you have 2 problems.

Comment: I like Python, thou I'd guess regex usage also there, it is more "portable" for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With RegexBuddy, you can do it in two steps.

First search for `(?<=(^\S.*$)(?s:.*?))^\s+` and replace all with `\1<space>`.

This gives you

```
header-1
header-1 item1-1
header-1 item1-2
header-1 item1-3
header-2
header-2 item2-1
header-2 item2-2
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=   # Make sure we're right after the following match:
 (     # Match and capture in group 1 (the header):
  ^    # From the start of the line...
  \S   # but only if the first character is not whitespace
  .*   # match any number of characters except newlines
  $    # until the end of the line (OK, that's redundant).
 )     # End of group 1
 (?s:  # Start a non-capturing group, DOTALL mode enabled
  .*?  # that matches any number of any character, as few as possible.
 )     # End of group
)      # End of lookbehind assertion
^\s+   # Now match one or more whitespace characters at the start of the line
```

Then search for `^(.*)$\r?\n(?=\1)` and replace with the empty string.

This results in

```
header-1 item1-1
header-1 item1-2
header-1 item1-3
header-2 item2-1
header-2 item2-2
```

**Explanation:**

```
^       # Match from the start of the line
(.*)    # Match and capture the entire line in group 1
$       # Match until the end of the line (OK, redundant again)
\r?\n   # Match a linebreak
(?=\1)  # Do all this only if the next line starts with the same string as above
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll add it in my regex snippets. I suspected lookbehind usage but that's still advanced for me. Cheers

Comment: What does the "s" in `(?s:...)` do?

Comment: @WayneConrad: It turns on the "dot matches all" mode for this part of the regex. In the lookbehind assertion, there's a dot that should only match non-linebreak characters, but in that group, the dot should match linebreaks as well.

Comment: Thanks.  This is a nice bit of regex-foo, and the explanation is excellent.